# Variable not defined (AppleScript)

Tags: applescript, automator

For some reason `the name of thePath` comes up as not defined by my Automator workflow.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set thePath to the (first item of the input)
        set namedFolder to ((the name of thePath) as text)
        set namedFolder to ((text 1 thru 13) of namedFolder)
    end tell
    return namedFolder
end run
```

Comment: Are you still a user of SOF? You have not responded to accept the apparently correct answer.

Comment: There are various reasons why a person might not respond. Checking SavgStorm's profile, for example, we see "Last seen Nov 11 '14 at 15:15" - a significant time prior to "Sep 10 '16 at 20:05". *Just upvote answers that work for you, and move on.*

Answer (score 4):

`namedFolder` only exists in the scope of your `tell` block. Define it first thing so that it will persist after you’re done with Finder.

```
set namedFolder to ""
tell application "Finder"
    ...
end tell
return namedFolder
```

Alternatively, you could just put the `return` statement inside the `tell` block.